# C# read file parse into array

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I'm trying to read an input file into an array. My file looks something like:

> 00000**5071177**M010165767HAZZ           JONES    FAKE          B M12/16/196901/06/2014000000036209
>   00000**5071178**M0201657677315    FAKE ST                                      MOON TX56464     485942934 MAINTENCE

I wish to push an entire line broken up by spaces into an array or object when the a pattern in the first word of the first line matches a pattern in the second block of the second line.

so my array will contain something like 
**[5071177] -> array([Jones, Fake,B, M12/16/196901,Fake ST, Moon,etc]);**
what's the best way to accomplish this?

```
StreamReader sR = new StreamReader("Desktop/records2.txt");
StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter("Desktop/new.txt");

while (sR.Peek() != -1) // stops when it reachs the end of the file
{
    string line = sR.ReadLine();
    //  var myArray = line.Split('\n');
    string[] myarray = line.Split(' ');
    // "line" EDITING GOES HERE
    sW.WriteLine(myarray); /
}
```

Comment: split on space, and do your logic ? ... what's the question?

Comment: The question is not clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create a class to hold your data:

```
public Record
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    /* etc */
}
```

Create a method in another class called something like `Parse()` that returns a `Record`.

```
public class RecordParser
{
    private List<string> rawRecords;

    public RecordParser()
    {
        rawRecords = new List<string>();
    }

    public RecordParser(string filePath)
    {
        rawRecords = new List<string>();
        rawRecords.AddRange(ReadLines(filePath));
    }

    public Record Parse(string raw)
    {
        // 00000*5071177*M010165767HAZZ JONES FAKE B M12/16/196901/06/2014000000036209 
        string[] myarray = line.Split(' ');
        Record record = new Record
        {
            Id = myarray[0].Split('*')[1],
            FirstName = myarray[1],
            LastName = myarray[2],
            DateOfBirth = myarray[3],
            /* etc */  
        };
        return record;
    }

    public List<Record> ParseAll()
    {
        if(!rawRecords.Any()) throw new ArgumentNullException("Nothing to parse.");

        var records = new List<Record>();
        foreach(string raw in rawRecords)
        {
           records.Add(Parse(raw));
        }
        return records;
    }

    private List<string> ReadLines(string path)
    {
        // exception handling needed.
        return File.ReadLines(path).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var recordParser = new RecordParser();
string data = "00000*5071177*M010165767HAZZ JONES FAKE B M12/16/196901/06/2014000000036209";
Record record = recordParser.Parse(data);

var recordParser = new RecordParser(@"C://data.txt");
List<Record> records = recordParser.ParseAll();
```

Comment: thanks for this i just started C# and know nothing of the syntax

Comment: You're welcome. You might need to do some additional logic because your sample strings don't seem to be exactly separated by spaces.

Comment: since im running the streamreader and writer from main how do i call  `public Record Parse(string raw)` if it's in another class just a simple function invocation like `parse(line)`?

Comment: I've added the usage of the class to my answer.

Comment: that last line `return file.Readlines(path)` gives me a Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2):

```
File.WriteAllLines(newFile, File.ReadAllLines(oldFile).Select((x) => 
{
    var arr = x.Split(' ');
    var id = arr[0].Split('*')[1];
    var spearatedData = string.Join(", ",  arr.Skip(0).ToArray() )
    return string.Format("[{0}] => ({1})", id, spearatedData);
}));
```

Comment: im getting  (System.IndexOutOfRangeException) on the `var id = arr[0].split('*')[1];` line can you explain this code little more

Comment: It gets `"B"` is string `"A*B*C"`. In your question you implied `B` was your Id.

Comment: @iomed oh i see there's no actual * in the file i just added it to emphasize that part of the line. could i do something like split on substring(7,15) ?

Comment: @Edward, please update your question with a clean (real) input sample.

Comment: @Edward, yes, you can write `arr[0].Substring(7, 7)` instead `arr[0].Split('*')[1];`